# php code logic is not okay, i suppose that

Tags: php, mysql

//page2 edit button code.. page2 send the data back to page1 if user wants to edit

```
<a href="purchase_form1.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="button4">Edit</a>
```

//page1 php code. here the form is on this page

```
//This GET[id] is sent from page2 which is user view page of the form on page1. 
//If user do not like the form he clicks on edit button (code above) and reaches this page
$id = 0;
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) 
{
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}
$query  = "SELECT * from db_purchase_form where id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$has_data = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $has_data = true;
    $product_name = $row[1];
    $choice_actor = $row[2];
    $user_name = $row[3];
    $user_email = $row[4];
    $vdo_script = $row[5];
    $hrt_msg = $row[6];
    $portApproval = $row[7];
    $delivery = $row[8];
    $net_price = $row[9];
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // here i am trying to UPDATE DB if the user edited the form AND CLICKS ON submit
    if ($has_data == true){
    $sql = "UPDATE db_purchase_form ". "SET db_product_name  = \".pSQL($product_name).'\' , db_actor = \".pSQL($choice_actor).'\', db_user_name = \".pSQL($user_name).'\', db_user_email = \".pSQL($user_email).'/', db_vdo_script = \".pSQL($vdo_script).'\', db_hrt_msg = \".pSQL($hrt_msg).'\', db_port_approval = \".pSQL($portApproval).'\', db_delivery = \".pSQL($delivery).'\', db_price = \".pSQL($net_price).'\', db_date_time = NOW()". "WHERE id = '{$id}'";
    }
// form validation and insert into DB if form is okay
```

what shall be happening is if the GET[id] is set then UPDATE query shall run i.e. user has edited the form and saving changes to that id, otherwise the new id shall be inserted.

What is happening is, when user clicks on edit on page2, and reaches page1 & make changes to page1 form and clicks submit, instead of updating the same ID the page is inserting a new id to the db.

Help friends!!!

but it is not working the way it shall be working, any help friends?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Casting to `int` is not a substitution for [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). I don't know what `pSQL` does, but it probably does it wrong, as you should never use wrapper functions for escaping. It hides mistakes that can have serious consequences.

Comment: @tadman can you provide the correct solution? thanks

Comment: There is no any insert statement. How come it is inserting a new row in the DB? Is this the complete code of the Page or missing something?

Comment: What happens when you execute the statement in phpMyAdmin/mysql Client? what is the table structure? A pure `UPDATE` does not insert. That's what `REPLACE` does.

Comment: What you're doing here is going to break down, most of it depends on chance to work at all. For example, `SELECT * FROM db_purchase_form` is not going to work if the order of the columns changes, an assumption that's going to bite you some day. This is what happens when you write your own database code using wildly out of date tutorials instead of using a [popular PHP framework](http://crunchify.com/the-5-most-relevant-php-frameworks-in-2013/) to provide a foundation for your application.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic needs to be udpated. Page1 should be the form which submits to another page.

```
// code for page1.php
// if this is an edit request from page2.php
if (isset($_GET['id']) && ($_GET['id'] != '')){
    $id = (int)htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);

    // get the information for this id from the database
    // YOU SHOULD USE mysqli/PDO here. THIS IS JUST FOR DEMO
    $query  = "SELECT * from db_purchase_form where id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    // pre-populate the current values that would be displayed
    // in the actual form that the user can edit from here on   
    $product_name = $row[1];
    $choice_actor = $row[2];
    $user_name = $row[3];
    $user_email = $row[4];
    $vdo_script = $row[5];
    $hrt_msg = $row[6];
    $portApproval = $row[7];
    $delivery = $row[8];
    $net_price = $row[9];
}
// this is not the edit case and the user wants to add a new product
else {
    // this is for product not present case
    $id = 0;
    $product_name = '';
    $choice_actor = '';
    $user_name = '';
    $user_email = '';
    $vdo_script = '';
    $hrt_msg = '';
    $portApproval = '';
    $delivery = '';
    $net_price = '';
}

// show the form here for both the cases
echo "<form name='form' method='POST' action='submit_form.php'>";
// here I am assuming that all inputs are of type text but you can change
// this to whatever your type is
echo "<input type='text' name='product_name' value='$product_name'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='choice_actor' value='$choice_actor'>";
/*
    rest of the form inputs go here just like the first one
*/
// id goes as hidden input to next page
// this will help decide if its an insert query or update query
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

then for your submit_form page

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit')){
    if ($_POST['id'] == '0'){
        // this is the add new product case
        // insert query goes here
    }
    else {
        // this is the update product case
        // update query goes here
    }
}
```

you still need to sanitize input for the submit_form.php page but this should take care of your basic logic.

Comment: i do not send the data to page2, because all my php validation is on page1

Comment: <form id="PurchaseForm" name="PurchaseForm" method="post" action="purchase_form1.php"> purchase_form1.php is the same page

Comment: that is OK. You can combine logic in my answer with your current code. This answer is there just to demonstrate a possible logic that you can implement.

Comment: can i show you the code i made for the page? somewhere? maybe in chat?

Comment: I would recommend that you try to go through my answer and see if you can make some changes to your current code based on my answer. If you are still having issues after you have made changes to your code, then I recommend posting your code for review on the CodeReview site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: because if i try to implement the format you shown above there will be a lot of changes, maybe i can show you the small code, then you can quickly tell the exact change needed?